# BadMatch error on XCreateWindow for InputOnly window

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I am trying to create a window with Xlib like this:

```
XSetWindowAttributes win_attribs;
::memset((void *)&win_attribs, 0, sizeof(win_attribs));
unsigned long win_attribs_mask;
win_attribs.override_redirect = True;
win_attribs_mask = CWOverrideRedirect;

Window win = XCreateWindow(display,
                        XDefaultRootWindow(display);
                        0,
                        0,
                        1, 1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        InputOnly,
                        CopyFromParent,
                        win_attribs_mask,
                        &win_attribs));
```

Which results in `X11 Error 8 (BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)): request 55.0`.

I have read the documentation which parameters might be wrong here:

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XCreateWindow.html

But I cannot figure out what is going on and why this error is spit out. The manual states that an `InputOnly` window needs a depth of `0`, a valid visual `which is the one from the parent` and can only set certaint window attributes (of which `CWOverrideRedirect`is one of).

Which parameter might be wrong here?

Comment: Can you expand your example to a compilable program with `main()`?